# LINQ to XML and GridView.ImageField

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, linq-to-xml, imagefield

i am wanting to know how to add an image to a gridview based on the imageurl in a xml document. so far i have...

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));

var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("Images")
        where c.Element("PropertyId").Value.ToString() == DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()
        select new
        {
            Id = c.Element("PropertyId").Value,
            Thumb = c.Element("ThumbUrl").Value                
        };
GridView1.DataSource = q;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

which works fine to show the url in the thumb field but instead of showing this how do i change it an image field?

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <ImageField DataImageUrlField="PhotoPath" />
    </Columns>
</<asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
string selectedValue =  DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(); // cache it!
var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("Images")
        where c.Element("PropertyId").Value.ToString() == selectedValue 
        select new
        {
            PhotoPath = c.Element("PhotoPath").Value         
        };

GridView1.DataSource = q;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

What is your problem?

Comment: yeah i can do that which is fine but only want the gridview to show the image not the filepatth which it currently does

Comment: @Kev: How does look like images' path? It should be relative to control containing the GridView. Or server-relative, e.g. `~/Images/foo.gif`

Comment: the gridview now has two columns. one the url of the image and next to it the image that is bound to it

Comment: @Kev: Is a path to image relative, absolute, or what?